# Ajax call using Laravel not working when ad blocker is enabled

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am using Laravel to send Ajax request, it works fine on localhost, but not on live server with adblocker enabled. Once I disable the adblocker it works fine.

```
domain.com/sponsors/update/1
```

This is URL which is creating issue, besides this, it works for all other routes.
Can you please let me know what could be the possible issue?

Comment: You can possibly check which rules are matched with this url when adblock is blocking request then you might get to some conclusions.

Comment: @Tomasz, you mean I should check all routes having sponsors in it and then rename it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have no impact if somebody is using adblock or not. Of course you could possibly ask user for disabling it before browsing page due to issues with functionality but IMHO it's not the best way to go.

What I would do is the following.
If you're using for example uBlock you can take a look on logger to discover which URL's are getting blocked and maybe you can as well further investigate from which list the rule that blocks your requests is coming. Maybe it's your own created rule by accident?

[image: Screenshot from uBlock Origin Mozzilla Addons page]

In case that it's not your own created rule and it comes from popular list used by many I would probably consider renaming my routes to use more "neutral" URL that would not be considered by adblocks as potential thread.